# How to specify typescript type of a component with properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component `SampleComponent.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

type Props = { text: string };

export const SampleComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({text})=><div>{text}</div>;

SampleComponent.variant1 = ({text})=><div>{'variant1' + text}</div>;
```

When I try using `SampleComponent.variant1` in other components, I get typescript error:

```
Property 'variant1' does not exist on type ...
```

Right now I am just casting type with `as`, but I think there is a better way.

How can I fix this?

**Edit:** How to type if I have dynamic variants - from 1 to 4 such - `.variant1`, `.variant2`, `.variant3` and `.variant4`

Answer (score 1):

Since you've said that Sample Component is an FC, react won't let you add any properties that aren't a part of FC. You can either expand the type you declare SampleComponent as, something like this:

```
export const SampleComponent: React.FC<Props> & {
  variant1: React.FC;
} = ({ text }) => <div>{text}</div>;

SampleComponent.variant1 = ({ text }) => <div>{"variant1" + text}</div>;
```

Or you can provide the type for the props but then let typescript figure out the rest by the way you use it:

```
const SampleComponent = ({ text }: Props) => <div>{text}</div>;

SampleComponent.variant1 = ({ text }: Props) => <div>{"variant1" + text}</div>;
```

Comment: thanks! how to type if `variant` is dynamic such as `variant1`, `variant2` etc.?

Comment: Do you know all the variants up front? Or do you need to be able to add arbitrary keys at runtime?

Comment: yes, only 4 types of variants with last number changing, edited question

Comment: Then the solutions i showed should work, you just need to add more lines to it. In example 1 that will look like `variant2: React.FC; variant3: React.FC`, etc. In example 2, your new lines will look very similar to line 2: `SampleComponent.variant2 = /* some component */`

Comment: is there a way to this with `enum` or union type?

Comment: Do i understand correctly: you have an enum or union, and then you want to say "SampleComponent is an object with all the keys found in that enum/union, and each of the keys corresponds to a React.FC"?

Comment: yes exactly, I tried to this with ` ... & { [key: VariantType]:FC<Props>}` but it didn't work

Comment: To restrict an index type to certain keys you would do use `in`: `[key in VariantType]: FC<Props>`. Though i'm playing around with it a bit, and while the type is correct, typescript can't figure out that SampleComponent actually fulfills that type and so gives an error

Comment: Unfortunately i've got to go so i can't experiment with it some more. I'll check back later in the day